# Reading spatial data from MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a website that manages points of interest, using PHP and MySQL. I decided to look at MySQL's Spatial Data features instead of saving the coordinates in two separate fields.

I managed to get the inserting of data into the database using the following:

```
// Update new records
$query = "UPDATE users SET users_address = :uaddress, users_placeid = :uplace, users_coords = POINTFROMTEXT(:location) "; 
$query .= "WHERE users_id = :uid ";
        // echo "Query: $query <br>";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute(array(':uaddress' => $users_address,
                               ':uplace' => $users_placeid,
                             ':location' => $location,
                                  ':uid' => $users_id));
        $result = $stmt;
```

Now I want to read the data and get the coordinates out, using PHP and PDO. There does not seem to be any examples on the Internet for using PDO, PHP and MySQL for spatial data.

My normal SELECT code is:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE users_id = :uid ");
$stmt->execute(array(':uid' => $users_id));
$result = $stmt;

if ($result->rowCount() > 0) {

  foreach($result as $row) {

    $users_address           = $row['users_address'];
    $users_placeid           = $row['users_placeid'];
    $users_lat               = $row['x.users_coords'];
     echo "Lat: $users_lat <br>";

  } 
}
```

I've tried various options and each one gives an error. The code above returns:

> Notice: Undefined index: x.users_coords

I want to stick to using SELECT * instead of SELECT users_address, etc. if possible.

The other option is to just return to using two fields for the coordinates, but that makes it more difficult to do distance measurements etc later.

Any idea how to extract Latitude and Longitudes?

Comment: Have you tried printing the $row objects to see what is in them?

Comment: I tried that. It give non-ascii text reply: [users_coords] => ԝ'��eA����pO4@    [23] => ԝ'��eA����pO4@

Answer (score 1):

After much frustration I managed to solve the problem. You have to specify the spatial data in the SELECT string and then it is easy to read the data. Here is full code to read the data:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT *, X(users_coords) AS users_lat, Y(users_coords) AS users_long FROM users WHERE users_id = :uid ");
$stmt->execute(array(':uid' => $users_id));
$result = $stmt;

if ($result->rowCount() > 0) {

  foreach($result as $row) {

    $users_address           = $row['users_address'];
    $users_placeid           = $row['users_placeid'];
    $users_lat               = $row['users_lat'];
    // echo "Lat: $users_lat <br>";
    $users_long              = $row['users_long'];
    // echo "Long: $users_long <br>";
  } 
}

?>
```